# Display a variable from a class in the console?

Tags: c#

I have written the following code, but I want to make sure a property can protect the original value of the variables `m_id` and `m_name`. Is there a way to display those two variables in the console? Thanks!

```
using System;

public class Customer
{
    private int m_id = -1;

    public int GetID()
    {
        return m_id;
    }

    public void SetID(int id)
    {
        m_id = id;
    }

    private string m_name = string.Empty;

    public string GetName()
    {
        return m_name;
    }

    public void SetName(string name)
    {
        m_name = name;
    }
}

public class CustomerManagerWithAccessorMethods {
    public static void Main()
    {
        Customer cust = new Customer();

        cust.SetID(1);
        cust.SetName("Amelio Rosales");

        Console.WriteLine(
            "ID: {0}, Name: {1}",
            cust.GetID(),
            cust.GetName());

        Console.ReadKey();
    } }
```

Comment: I don't understand the question at all. The code runs fine as it is, and I don't see a problem with it (apart from style nits). You do not have any properties here either, just a bunch of private fields and public methods that expose them (which isn't the same as a .NET/C# property). And I do not understand what you mean by "make sure a property can protect the original value". Please explain.

Answer (score 2):

Change your class definition to this if you want to use properties:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }    
}
```

and then just modify the code...which is already printing the values to the console (?).

```
Console.WriteLine( "ID: {0}, Name: {1}", cust.Id, cust.Name );
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're already doing it (although idiomatic C# would use *properties* instead of *methods*).

What exactly do you mean by "protecting" the original value of `m_id` and `m_name`?